# Using jq, how do I convert an array of objects where two properties make up a "key" to an indexed object of objects?

Tags: json, jq

I have this input JSON array (already slightly preprocessed from turborepo's --dry-run=json output)

```
{
  "package": "@nullvoxpopuli/dev",
  "task": "_syncPnpm",
  "local": false,
  "remote": false,
  "status": "MISS",
  "timeSaved": 0
}
{
  "package": "@nullvoxpopuli/dev",
  "task": "test",
  "local": false,
  "remote": false,
  "status": "MISS",
  "timeSaved": 0
}
{ 
  "package": "another-package",
  ...
  ... etc
```

I'd like to transform this data in to the following shape:

```
{
  "@nullvoxpopuli/dev": {
    "_syncPnpm": {
      "local": false,
      "remote": false,
      "status": "MISS",
      "timeSaved": 0
    },
    "test": {
      "local": false,
      "remote": false,
      "status": "MISS",
      "timeSaved": 0  
    }
  }
}
```

The schem(e|a) for this transform is:

```
{
  [package]: {
    [task]: {
      ...the other fields
    }
  }
}
```

This would allow me to use GitHub actions to skip jobs based on cache status, which would help save the environment

I've been using https://jqplay.org/ to test out stuff before I bring the solution to the command line, and most of my problem is just that I don't know the foundations of jq well enough.

I think I need to use reduce, but building new nested objects is escaping my understanding.

ChatGPT suggested this:

```
reduce .[] as $item ({};
    .[$item.package][$item.task] += [$item]
)
```

but that gives me this error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1072): Cannot index string with string "task"
exit status 5
```

which I don't know what to do about.
It *sounds* like it's trying to iterate over a string, but I don't know why it would do that?
The error could def be a lot more clear.

I also found this site: https://remysharp.com/drafts/jq-recipes
which generally suggests the same thing -- at least the reduce syntax looks correct.
Maybe it's the nested object creation part that ChatGPT got wrong.
(It's also something that's very hard to google for, and I haven't found anyone doing what I want yet)

I also tried a technique that I use in JavaScript for this sort of thing, but I don't think this is correct either:

```
reduce .[] as $item ({};
    .[$item.package] ||= {}
    .[$item.package][$item.task] ||= {}
    .[$item.package][$item.task] += [$item]
)
```

as I get the error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected |= (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 4:
    .[$item.package] ||= {}                      
jq: 1 compile error
exit status 3
```

so... I don't know if jq has the concept of "or, equals"

Here is my jq-play link: https://jqplay.org/s/mFZdK_Gz4WE

Comment: Why limit yourself to `jq`? If you're using Turborepo you're presumably doing something with JavaScript, in which this would be trivial.

Comment: jq is fast, node is not, and node has quite the boot time.

Comment: `jq` is faster, sure, but how many tens of milliseconds have elapsed since you posted the question? How many more since you started trying to figure this out? Roughly how many (tens of thousands of) times would this have to be executed before `jq` is actually net faster? GHA takes whole seconds to start each job; any difference here would be lost in the noise anyway.

Comment: this isn't a helpful discussion. I'm not trying to "solve a use case" I could have already done, as you've pointed out. I want to use a specific technology to solve a problem _because I want to_.

Also, in my testing, I would save 3s per CI run by using jq -- that adds up very quickly with how many PRs my repos get (renovate)

Comment: 3s * 10 repos * minimum 20 PRs per week = 10 minutes wasted each week, or 520 minutes or 8.66 Hours wasted each year. 
If I can get *more* repos using this technique, then the savings are even better

Comment: The errors you posted, `||=` is not valid syntax. I think you're trying to do an updating assignment? That's `|=`. `||=` is parsed as "pipe (for next filter) then unexpected '|='"

Comment: I tried `|=`, too, and get another syntax error: `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 5:
    .[$item.package][$item.task] |= {}     
jq: 1 compile error
exit status 3`

https://jqplay.org/s/sBDutZWbzMo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input appears to be a stream of the objects. You have the right idea but execution is off. `||=` is not valid syntax, you probably meant `|=`.

You can use jq's pattern binding syntax in a similar fashion to javascript to pull out certain properties of an object. Though, there isn't a "rest" syntax for the unbound properties, but we can work around that. Then construct the result. You can take shortcuts here as jq assumes an object when performing assignments to properties.

```
$ jq -n 'reduce (inputs|[.,del(.package,.task)]) as [{$package,$task},$rest] ({};
  .[$package][$task] |= $rest
)'
{
  "@nullvoxpopuli/dev": {
    "_syncPnpm": {
      "local": false,
      "remote": false,
      "status": "MISS",
      "timeSaved": 0
    },
    "test": {
      "local": false,
      "remote": false,
      "status": "MISS",
      "timeSaved": 0
    }
  }
}
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/ir-BQqyZYyv)

Comment: oh thank you! this works great! 
Here is my full version using the turborepo output: https://jqplay.org/s/yZWp6x4G3xD

Comment: tho, I messed up something in my adaptation 

Comment: You could simplify that significantly in your version by removing the intermediate step of  the "simplifying" the task objects. Also, you'll want to expand the tasks within the reduce  input binding so that you can get the results all into a single object like you were aiming for. `reduce .tasks[] as {$package,$task,$cache} ...` https://jqplay.org/s/g1NZ1sAB_F_Q

Comment: oh thanks! that's way simpler!